# Illustrator Script to create Clipping Mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator, javascript

How is it possible to create a clipping mask with a illustrator javascript script?

I tried this, but it doesnt work.

```
    var group = app.activeDocument.groupItems.add();

    var rect = layer.pathItems.rectangle( height, 0.0, width, height );
    rect.moveToBeginning( group );

    var ellipse = layer.pathItems.ellipse(ellipseLeft, ellipseTop, ellipseWidth, ellipseWidth);
    ellipse.clipping = true;
    ellipse.moveToBeginning( group );
```

What i need is a working code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the group to be `clipped` too (after adding your paths). I believe setting the ellipse to be the clipping mask is unnecessary if it is the last object you add (the top object in the group should become the clipping path if you don't specify).

```
var group = app.activeDocument.groupItems.add();

var rect = layer.pathItems.rectangle( height, 0.0, width, height );
rect.moveToBeginning( group );

var ellipse = layer.pathItems.ellipse(ellipseLeft, ellipseTop, ellipseWidth, ellipseWidth);
ellipse.clipping = true;
ellipse.moveToBeginning( group );

group.clipped = true; // <-- Add this after adding your paths to the group.
```